# How to make the title field of a node/add form hidden or locked

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm prepopulating the title of the node/add/content_type using the URL. I would like this form to be hidden or locked so that the user can't accidentally edit it. I've been looking though the Drupal documentation and haven't found a way to hide fields at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably just hide it with CSS to be honest.

Either that, or I'd use [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) to populate the title with tokens (path token in your case) as it has the option to hide the title field AND auto-generate it with minimal effort.

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
> the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
> fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.
>
> When the token module is installed it's possible to use various node
> data for the auto generated title - e.g. use the text of a CCK field
> (since 5.x).

Another option would be to use `hook_form_alter()` and set `#disabled` to `TRUE` to disable user input.

Comment: This works for me: 
**$form['title']['#attributes'] = array('value' => 'Test');
$form['title']['#disabled'] = TRUE;**

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to simply hide the title element in your node edit form. I also think you should be able to achive this by using the `hook_node_presave()`, something like this would work:

```
function YOURMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  // you may also wan't to check the 'status' of the node
  if($node->nid && $node->type == 'your-custom-content-type') {
     // check if title has changed
     if($node->title != 'your-prepopulated-value') {
        // notify user that the update couldn't be performed
        drupal_set_message('You may not change the title of this kind of nodes!','warning');
        // set node to null to force making no changes
        $node = null;
     }
  }
  return $node;
}
```

Comment: You could also just re-assign the changed `$node->title` to your desired node title in this hook.